# React array not updating when deleting or editing an item, from database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of items, where i can delete, view and edit a Post.
But when i delete one of the items, by clicking the delete button, it doesn't update the list in React (but does in my database, so the request works).

**My Profile.js component**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import DbContext from "../../../context/DbContext";
import ForumIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Forum";

// import history from "../history";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import confirm from "reactstrap-confirm";
import { IconButton } from "@material-ui/core";

import { PencilSquare, Eye } from "react-bootstrap-icons";

const Profile = (props) => {
  // getting  posts
  const [post, setPost] = useState();
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const context = useContext(DbContext);
  const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    context.getPosts().then((x) => setPost(x));
    setUser(context.getUser());
  }, [context.existsUser()]);

  // delete
  const handleDelete = useCallback(async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    context.deletePost(event.target.id);
  });

 
  return (
    <>
      <section className="container-fluid my-2">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-3">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <img
                    className="img-fluid"
               
                    alt="Profile image"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="col-12">
                  <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                      Alder:{" "}
                      <span className="text-right">
                        {new Date().getFullYear() -
                          new Date(user?.dateOfBirth).getFullYear()}
                      </span>
                    </li>
                    <li className="list-group-item">
                      Location: {user?.location}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-9">
            {/* Edit User */}
            <Link
              to="/editUser"
              className="btn btn-primary position-absolute"
              style={{ right: 15, top: 50 }}
            >
              Rediger bruger
            </Link>
            {/* Create Post */}
            <Link
              to="/createpost"
              className="btn btn-primary position-absolute"
              style={{ right: 15, top: 100 }}
            >
              Opret annonce
            </Link>
            <hr />
            <p> {user?.contentBio}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

 

      {/* Posts */}
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <h1>Dine annoncer</h1>
            <table className="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Oprettet</th>
                  <th scope="col">Annonce titel</th>
                  <th scope="col">Pris</th>
                  <th scope="col">Se/Rediger/Slet</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {user?.posts && user?.posts.length > 0
                  ? user.posts.map((post) => (
                      <tr key={post.id}>
                        <th scope="row">{post.date}</th>
                        <td>{post.title}</td>
                        <td>{post.price} kr.</td>
                        <td>
                          <Link
                            to={`/showpost/${post.id}`}
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-primary"
                          >
                            <Eye />
                          </Link>
                          <Link
                            to={`/editpost/${post.id}`}
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-success"
                          >
                            <PencilSquare />
                          </Link>
                          <Link
                            to=""
                            id={post.id}
                            onClick={handleDelete}
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-danger"
                          >
                            {/* THIS IS MY DELE BUTTON */}
                            DELETE
                          </Link>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    ))
                  : "No posts"}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

**Method to refresh user in my DbProvider.js:**

```
 refreshUser: async () => {
            try {
              await axios
                .get(
                  baseApi +
                    `users/login?email=${user.email}&password=${user.password}`
                )
                .then((x) => {
                  setUser(x.data);
                  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(x.data));
                  forceUpdate();
                });
            } catch (err) {
              return false;
            }
          }
```

**My Delete method in DbProvider.js:**

```
 deletePost: async (id) => {
            let response = await axios.delete(baseApi + `posts/` + id);
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
          }
```

**UPDATE**
getPosts method in DbProvider

```
  getPosts: async () => {
            let response = await axios.get(baseApi + `posts`);

            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
          },
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there, but I don't see you using `setPost` to update the post prop after it's deleted. It seems as if you delete it from the DB but you don't unset the reference to that post in the frontend.

Comment: Is `deletePost` returning a new array of posts without the deleted one? In that case just do `setPost(context.deletePost(event.target.id))` otherwise you need to do again this `context.getPosts().then((x) => setPost(x));`. Also pay attention to naming convention: getPostS -> setPostS if you use plural stick with plural.

Comment: @shidoro Like so ?:
`code
  const handleDelete = useCallback(async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();


    setPost(context.deletePost(event.target.id))
    context.getPosts().then((x) => setPost(x));
  });
`
I can see in the console that it does not return the new array

Comment: @perepm how would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `deletePost` does not return the new array then fetch your posts again

```
const handleDelete = useCallback(async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  await context.deletePost(event.target.id);
  const newPosts = await context.getPosts();
  setPost(
    newPosts.filter( post => post.userId === user.id )
  );
});
```

**UPDATE**

you might also want to change this code

```
useEffect(() => {
    context.getPosts().then((x) => setPost(x));
    setUser(context.getUser());
  }, [context.existsUser()]);
```

to

```
useEffect(() => {
    setUser(context.getUser());
  }, [context.existsUser()]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    context.getPosts().then((x) =>
      setPost(x.filter(post => post.userId === user.id));
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: Does not work. I have updated the question, with my getPosts(). Could it be because of the url, where i want to show the list? (http://localhost:3000/#/profile)

Comment: You are not rendering the posts through mapping the `post` array, but you're using instead `user.posts` that might be why you don't see the update. Change this line `{user?.posts && user?.posts.length > 0? user.posts.map` to `{post && post.length ? post.map`

Comment: This works! But now i see all the posts (also those who are made by other users)
A user should only be able to see hes own posts

Comment: Then filter when setting the posts. I don't know how neither how the user object looks like nor how the post object looks, but I assume each post object has a `userId` associated with it so: `setUser(newPosts.filter( post => /* here you match the id of the user to the userId in the post object */))`

Comment: Something like this?: `setUser(newPosts.filter( post => post.userId == currentUser.id  ))`
Yes, every Post has a UserId.
What information do i need to provide?

Comment: Yes but `currentUser` doesn't exist in your code. So use the `user` state variable you have already declared on the top. `post.userId === user.id`

Comment: Where should i place the code?

Comment: It works!! Although i have to run the handleDelete before it filters the array

Comment: Thank you so so so much for your time!!!